# Deploying different git branches to subfolder / subdomain

Tags: git, deployment, staging

I have github account and I'm trying to create automatic deployments to my `dev` and `staging` environments from the respective branches from github.

The problem I'm facing is that both `dev.mysite.org` and `staging.mysite.org` are subfolders of my `public_html` directory.

i.e.

> public_html `(production)`
>
> > public_html/dev
> >
> > public_html/staging

I've already added them in the `.gitignore` file but how can I set them as independent repositories and then have the post-update file to do different pulls depending on which branch was updated in guthub?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to submodule for this purpose.

> A `submodule` allows you to keep another Git repository in a subdirectory of your repository.
>
> The other repository has its own history, which does not interfere with the history of the current repository.
>
> This can be used to have external dependencies such as third party libraries for example.
>
> When cloning or pulling a repository containing submodules however,
>      **these will not be checked out by default**;
>
> the `init` and `update` subcommands will maintain submodules checked out and at appropriate revision in your working tree.

---

```
// Add the submodules to your project
git submodule add <url> name
git submodule add <url1> name1

// init the submodule 
git submodule init

// Update the code
git submodule update
```

Now you can use them as separate repository inside your root repository

---

[image]